# p4 revert -w option not deleting file properly

Tags: perforce

According to the `p4 help revert`, I get:

```
    The -w flag causes files that are open for add to be deleted from the
    workspace when they are reverted.
```

But, when I try to use the -w, I get the following:

```
> p4 revert -w ./dir1/newfile.c
//depot/test/dir1/newfile.c#1 - was add, reverted
> ls ./dir1/newfile.c
./dir1/newfile.c
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in p4?  (Note: my version is as follows):

```
Proxy version: P4P/LINUX26X86_64/2014.2/1099171 (2015/06/16)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right.  I'd suggest contacting Perforce about this -- they'll have questions for you to try to debug what's going on.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm contacting p4.  I get different behavior depending on whether I add the file via `p4 add` or `p4 unshelve`  (the former working, the latter giving me the above).

Comment: More information for anyone who happens across this while debugging the same issue: the file being added was in the depot previously, but was deleted (rev#2 was deleted).   This seems to be the actual problem.   When you unshelve a changelist with a file that is being re-added, the file revision seems to become corrupted, and the revert no longer works properly.   I have notified perforce.

Answer (score 0):

"p4 revert" only undoes the operations that haven't been submitted yet. 
It will not delete the file from disk. You should delete the file separately after reverting.